# PowerMockRunner Tests working on Eclipse fail on STS by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: spring, junit4, powermock, powermockito, powermockrunner

I'm running a project with some JUnit4 tests that are using PowerMockRunner on Eclipse with no problem, all tests ok.
But running the same on Spring Tool Suite (over Eclipse), those tests that use PowerMockRunner fail by initializationError caused by the following trace:

*org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:55)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:38)
at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:58)
at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:91)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:222)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:158)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:181)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:96)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:89)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:45)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @37883b97 cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:238)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:182)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:238)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:182)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2189)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:65)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:400)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.generateConstructor(ReflectionFactory.java:466)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:379)
at jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:98)
... 35 more*

I'm using PowerMock as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SecurityContextHolder.class) //the static class that I have to acces
public class ClassToTest {

@Mock 
SecurityContext mockSecurityContext;

//... @Before injecting the mocks to the sut

public void methodThatUsesPowerMockClass {

//... some stuff here
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class):

Mockito.when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(mockSecurityContext):

}
```

I've been trying using:

@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*",
"org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*" })

at the beginning of the class but problem persists.